# Authentication problems with Mulesoft and Salesforce

Tags: authentication, salesforce, mule

I have a Mule application which uses the Salesforce connector. 
When I started developing this application, I first used oAuth to connect to Salesforce, but it kept giving me the following error: `Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: <key>`, so I switched to basic authentication for Salesforce.

This has worked great, but now, after some time, the application still throws the `Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: <key>` error.

This is unexpected behaviour, since each request contains the username, password and secret token.

It looks to me like some old version is in the Mule cache or something, which makes it want to use the oAuth method again. Is this a possibility?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

@Sytze You need to check the flag in the Salesforce connector for all applications sharing the same user credentials to Disable session invalidation (disableSessionInvalidation="true").  What is likely happening is one of your other applications is invalidating the session while your current app still believes its active.

Answer (score 0):

In the connector configuration , check for the correct Token code ( generated via sfdc ) .

Update the latest code and try again

Answer (score -1):

Your security token that you add with your password while calling it would have expired. Create a new token for you account/email-id in salesforce and use that and it should work

Best would be to use the oAuth to call salesforce.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Once I redeploy the application, it starts working again, with the same security code. Also, oAuth isn't the right solution here, since it's one server/user making all the requests.

Comment: @Sytze So after a redeploy, does it take a certain amount of time for the error to come up again? Does it always take the same amount of time? Does the error happen intermittently, or does it happen for every request once it does come up?

Comment: I guess the issue is that when we connect to the sales force it creates a session and then it expires. Can you check if you could stop/close the connection and then start automatically after a few hours ?

Comment: @Egor, it feels like a certain time, I can't be sure but it's multiple hours atleast. Also, once the error pops up, it pops up every request from then.

Comment: The weird thing also is, I have another app which uses the same type of authentication, and this one never fails...

Comment: Can you help me understand how those two applications are different say one application has inbound SFDC and other is Outbound or One is create and other is update ?

Comment: @NaveenRaj The use different Salesforce environments, both to login.salesforce.com, but different credentials.